# Get specific element inside other element with HtmlAgilityPack in C#

Tags: c#, html, mono

I'm working on a project where I need to parse a lot of html files. I need to get every `<p>` from within one `<div class="story-body">`

So far I have this code and it does what I want, but I was wondering how to do this using the xpath expression. I tried this:

```
textBody.SelectNodes ("What to put here? I tried //p but it gives every p in document not inside the one div")
```

But without success. Any ideas?

```
public void Parse(){
   HtmlNode title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode ("//h1[(@class='story-header')]");
   HtmlNode textBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode ("//div[(@class='story-body')]");

   XmlText textT;
   XmlText textS;

   string story = "";

   if(title != null){
     textT = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(title.InnerText);
     titleElement.AppendChild(textT);
     Console.WriteLine(title.InnerText);
   }

   foreach (HtmlNode node in textBody.ChildNodes) {
      if(node.Name == "p" || (node.Name == "span" && node.GetAttributeValue("class", "class") == "cross-head")){
         story += node.InnerText + "\n\n";
         Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
      }
   }

   textS = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode (story);

   storyElement.AppendChild (textS);

   try
   {
        xmlDoc.Save("test.xml");            
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a rather simple thing to do, you just have to add a `.` to the string like `.//p`, that way you get only child nodes of the current node.

Another way would be to just call SelectNodes like this:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[(@class='story-body')]/p");
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right it is simple.
However I ended with my original approach as I have to check more things and I don't think that it could be achived with xpath