# How To Get Div inside Div htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

first .. sorry about my bad english

my question is how can i scrape div inside div in htmlagilitypack c#

this is test html code

```
<html>
  <div class="all_ads">

    <div class="ads__item">
       <div class="test">
          test 1
         </div>
     </div>

    <div class="ads__item">
       <div class="test">
          test 2
         </div>
     </div>

    <div class="ads__item">
       <div class="test">
          test 3
         </div>
     </div>

  </div>
</html>
```

how to make a loop that get all ads then loop that control test inside ads

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388538/get-specific-element-inside-other-element-with-htmlagilitypack-in-c-sharp

Comment: can you guys put the code because when i write something like this it doesnt work

Comment: this is not a free coding service.  show us your effort and we can help you help yourself.

Comment: @MostafaM.Mead you should write and show us some thing so that we would be able to understand what specific thing is not working in your case.

Comment: edited guys now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the nodes inside class `all_ads` as follow:-

```
var res = div.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='all_ads ads__item']");
```

`.//div[@class='all_ads ads__item']` This will select all the nodes inside `all_ads`which has class `ads_item`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this path => `//div[contains(@class, 'test')]`

This means you need to select those div(s) that contains class with name ads__item.
and then select all those selected div(s) inner html. like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your html file");

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var innerContent = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'test')]").Select(x => x.InnerHtml.Trim());

        foreach (var item in innerContent)
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @MostafaM.Mead, answer updated. just replace `ads__item` class name with `test` in above path

Comment: can i make your code but with nested foreach ? , if yes then please edit your question

Comment: @MostafaM.Mead, why nested foreach? When your output comes with single foreach like above answer